# C# - Reading a long from Java's DataOutputStream

Tags: java, c#

I'm using the [DataOutputStream#WriteLong](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#DataOutputStream.writeLong%28long%29) method in the java programming language to write a long to a stream, and I need to be able to read it from C# using the [BinaryReader](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/BinaryReader@cs/1305376/BinaryReader@cs) class from C# to try to read the data, the BinaryReader is connected to a `NetworkStream`that uses the TcpClient socket.

The java [DataInputStream#ReadLong](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataInputStream.java#DataInputStream.readLong%28%29) method is used to read the long value sent from the DataOutputStream in Java, however I'm trying to use the BinaryReader class to read this value.

Here's the method I have to read a long variable in C#

```
public static long ReadLong()
{
    return binaryReader.ReadInt64();
}
```

However this is causing inconsistency, For example, I sent two longs through Java:

```
-8328681194717166436 || -5321661121193135183
```

and when I read them on C# I received the following results:

```
 -7186504045004821876||-5642088012899080778
```

I can reproduce this as many times as I fun the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in the java documentation, `WriteLong` writes output "high bytes first", this is also known as [Big Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Meanwhile, .NET BinaryReader reads data as Little Endian. We need something that reverses the bytes:

```
public class BigEndianBinaryReader : BinaryReader
{
    private byte[] a16 = new byte[2];
    private byte[] a32 = new byte[4];
    private byte[] a64 = new byte[8];

    public BigEndianBinaryReader(Stream stream) : base(stream) { }

    public override int ReadInt32()
    {
        a32 = base.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(a32);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(a32, 0);
    }

    public Int16 ReadInt16BigEndian()
    {
        a16 = base.ReadBytes(2);
        Array.Reverse(a16);
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(a16, 0);
    }

    public Int64 ReadInt64BigEndian()
    {
        a64 = base.ReadBytes(8);
        Array.Reverse(a64);
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(a64, 0);
    }

    public UInt32 ReadUInt32BigEndian()
    {
        a32 = base.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(a32);
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(a32, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: So many days of overlooking the order of bytes even though it was right in-front of my face. Thanks for the link on `Endianness` it certainly helped my understanding quite a bit. -- Shouldn't I be using `short, int, long` here instead of `Int16, Int32, Int64`?

Comment: short, int and long are synonymous for Int16, Int32 and Int64, as well as string is the same as String.

Comment: However, I've read that Int16, Int32, and Int64 can return null, while short, int, and long cannot.

Comment: That's not true. At least in .NET. For Java, there seems to be a difference.