# Reading binary file of doubles written in Java with ObjectOutputStream in Python with numpy.fromfile

Tags: java, python, numpy

I've written an array of doubles in binary format to a file using the ObjectOutputStream's writeDouble() function in Java. When I try to read this file on Python using numpy.fromfile, it doesn't give me the same values. When I try to move around in bits using seek(), it still doesn't help.

If I do the same procedure with 32 bit int, it works, but there's always a bit of the beginning of the file I need to iterate past using seek() because it's just gibberish I can't distinguish.

Relevant Java code:

```
//arr is an array of type double
try {    
      ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.bin"));
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        out.writeDouble(arr[i]);
      } 
      out.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Project.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

Relevant Python code:

```
datafile1 = open("data.bin", "rb")      
data = np.fromfile(datafile1, dtype=np.float64, count=-1, sep='')  

print data
```

Comment: The object output stream serializes Java objects - it's not well suited as transport to other languages. You would be better off writing your values in some format (CSV, JSON, XML, etc...) that is more easily parsed both ends, rather than trying to make this work. Edit: Or in this case, explicitly writing it in the format numpy expects.

Comment: How do I explicitly write it in the format numpy expects? I thought Java's double and numpy's float64 were the same. Thank you so much.

Comment: There appears to be [a format spec](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html) - personally, I'd write it out as CSV from Java, and then read it in with [`numpy.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt). I'm not a `numpy` user though, so there could be a better way.

Comment: Try a `DataOutputStream dos` and call `dos.writeDouble( double v )` for each double. Keep your fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same, but now no metadata is added to the file:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("data.bin");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( os );
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    dos.writeDouble(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work :( Maybe writing the bin file in .npy format might help hopefully. Thanks for your help

Comment: Write a few numbers and compare. Could be that .npy is not simply binary double in 8 bytes, high byte first. Also, try `dos.writeLong( Double.doubleToLongBits(double value) )`.

Comment: @henri: If you use this method, try reading the data with `np.fromfile("data.bin", dtype='>f8')`.  That `dtype` argument tells `fromfile` that the floating point values are stored in "big-endian" format.

Comment: I just tried a simple example, and by using the argument `dtype='>f8'` in `fromfile`, this worked for me.

Comment: Wow the '>f8' worked. Thank you so much! i appreciate all your help too guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few years. For posterity, here's how I got this to work with `DataOutputStream.writeFloat()`.

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681630, `DataOutputStream` writes in Big Endian. Numpy apparently expects binary files to be written in Little Endian, the reverse of that. The solution is to perform `byteswap()` on the received array.

```
np.fromfile('filename', np.float32).byteswap()
```

As you're working with `double`s, I suspect you'd need to pass in `np.float64` as the second argument instead. If that doesn't work, here's numpy's full list of `dtype`s:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: I think numpy can handle either endian, if you tell it what to expect. Is byteswap in this context a portable solution?